# Как передать файл из одного докер контейнера в другой и запустить его там?

Tags: docker

Один контейнер создает файл с иходным текстом программы, после этого я хочу забилдить другой контейнер, запустить в нем этот самый файл, получить результат и удалить контейнер в котором запускала. Как это правильно делают? как должны взаимодействовать контейнеры?

Правильный ли вариант, что второй контейнер находится внутри первого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«docker-контейнер» — это всего лишь процесс, запущенный в ограниченном, специально подготовленном для него окружении.

с участием программы docker всё точно так же, как и без её участия: запускаете один процесс, который формирует файл, затем запускаете другой процесс, который ещё что-нибудь делает с этим файлом.

единственное в данном случае отличие: так как процессы запускаются с собственными файловыми системами, надо позаботиться о том, чтобы файл сохранялся после завершения первого процесса, а потом его же можно было передать второму процессу.

например, при запуске обоих процессов можно воспользоваться опцией `-v` и передавать им одно и то же значение в этой опции:

```
$ docker run -v /путь/к/каталогу/с/вашим/файлом:/путь/внутри/контейнера ...
```

тогда оба процесса увидят содержимое каталога **вашей** файловой системы `/путь/к/каталогу/с/вашим/файлом` в **своей** файловой системе по пути `/путь/внутри/контейнера`. первый процесс создаст там файл, второй процесс воспользуется этим файлом.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо большое, а если первый контейнер работает буквально 24/7 (это django приложение), такой подход сработает?

Comment: если процесс не завершается, то вам по каким-то иным признакам надо будет определять, что «файл готов». собственно, абсолютно аналогичная задача, как и без программы docker.